# Group by frequency every N hours?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with the following index:

```py
DatetimeIndex(['2020-12-31 23:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 00:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 01:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 02:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 03:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 04:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 05:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 06:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-01-01 07:00:00+00:00', '2021-01-01 08:00:00+00:00',
               ...
               '2021-02-11 05:00:00+00:00', '2021-02-11 06:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-02-11 07:00:00+00:00', '2021-02-11 08:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-02-11 09:00:00+00:00', '2021-02-11 10:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-02-11 11:00:00+00:00', '2021-02-11 12:00:00+00:00',
               '2021-02-11 13:00:00+00:00', '2021-02-11 14:00:00+00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, UTC]', length=1000, freq='H')
```

I want to group this dataframe to groups lasting 8 hours, every four hours. Whereas using something like

```py
 df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="8H", offset=timedelta(hours=-1)))
```

results in groups that last 8 hours but every 8 hours.

i.e. my ideal result would have groups which overlap every four hours - is this possible?

Comment: @Corralien Have updated. There were missing values from the df, but the df is irrelevant, so lets assume the index is the following as above

`start = pd.to_datetime("2020-12-31 23:00:00+00:00", utc=True)`
`end = pd.to_datetime("2021-02-11 14:00:00+00:00", utc=True)`
`index = pd.date_range(data.index.min(), data.index.max(), freq="1H")`

Comment: What do you want to apply on this groups?

Comment: I have various aggregations, e.g. `grouped.apply(lambda g: g.iloc[1+np.argmax(g[:-1]) :].min())` to get the smallest value after the maximum value, `grouped.max()` to just get the maximum value, and `grouped.apply(list)` to get the list of values in the groups (all aggs have separate use cases).

Comment: And my last question. what hours should be selected for the group '2021-02-11 14:00:00' for example? I wonder if you are not looking for `Rolling` instead

Comment: I need specifically 23:00,  3:00, 7:00, 11:00, 15:00, 19:00 on each day. Im not sure exactly how to achieve this with `Rolling`

Comment: So for 07:00, you want 07->14 and for 11:00, you want 11->18 and so on, that's right?

Comment: Yep, exactly! covering an 8 hour span every 4 hours

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use 2 groups to accomplish that:

```
dti = pd.date_range('2020-12-31 23:00:00', '2021-02-11 14:00:00', freq='1H')
df = pd.DataFrame(range(len(dti)), index=dti)

grp1 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="8H", offset='-1hour'))
grp2 = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="8H", offset='-5hour'))
grps = [grp1, grp2]

data = []
for grp in grps:
    # do stuff here
    # result = grp.agg(...)
    result = grp.sum()
    data.append(result)

out = pd.concat(data).sort_index()
```

Output:

```
>>> out
                        0
2020-12-31 19:00:00     6
2020-12-31 23:00:00    28
2021-01-01 03:00:00    60
2021-01-01 07:00:00    92
2021-01-01 11:00:00   124
...                   ...
2021-02-10 19:00:00  7868
2021-02-10 23:00:00  7900
2021-02-11 03:00:00  7932
2021-02-11 07:00:00  7964
2021-02-11 11:00:00  3990  # <- only 4 hours here.

[251 rows x 1 columns]
```